# Detect When user click on Marker "Title"

Tags: android, google-maps

Currently, I detect when user tap on Google Map maker as follow:

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

                 // ---- copy to clipbored

                copyToClip(marker.getSnippet());

                return false;
            }
        });
```

However, I would prefer to detect when user tab on the "title" or snippet of the map marker (instead of the marker itself).

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code..

```
mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
               // TODO
            }
        });
```

Comment: the issue it says: setOnInfoWindowClickListener in Googlemap is not applicable